# PhoneGap Media plugins

Tags: ios5, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I am new at `Cordova PhoneGap`. In my project there is a one requirement.e.g. Capturing video,audio and upload it to server. I found the two plugins are available for do the same task.e.g. To access the camera in device, both Camera and Capture plugins are providing the same functionality. In addition, Capture is providing image,video,audio features.I am wondering which plugin should i go for.What is the difference between Camera,Media Vs Capture plugin?

It would be more helpful,if anyone can elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is that the `Camera` API uses the default Camera on the device, while the `Capture` API uses whichever application is set as the default on the device. So for example, if somebody has downloaded a different camera or audio recording app from a store, Capture will use that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am wondering.Is it possible in iPhone to change the default camera or music app to some other third party app for accessing the camera or mic?

Comment: I think if you wanted to do this from your app, then you would have to write a plugin to identify if the phone has the specific app, and if so, launch it. If you are asking if it is possible for the user to change the default camera or music app on their phone, I'm not sure (I even have an iPhone, d'oh.) I think what will happen is if they have multiple apps, a popup will pop up asking which application they want to use.